# OpenVPN server cluster - CentOS 7 - 2 VM's with Virtual IP - UDP 1194

Tags: openvpn, centos7, virtual-machines, high-availability

I need to configure an ha cluster for OpenVPN server. I'm using 2 VM's behind a firewall with a public static IP. I tried to use pacemaker + corosync with virtual ip. I can connect usign SSH using Virtual IP but when I tried to add OpenVPN service(systemd) to pacemaker it dos not works. Is it the right way to have cluster of OpenVPN server? Could you help me to find the correct solution or the right way to run my solution?

Thank you very much!! Have a nice day!!